# How do you make javascript(including function with array and return) write in div on button click without going to another page

Tags: javascript, html, forms, function, input

I have had a lot of problems with this problem. When I `console.log(sum);` I get the answer I am looking for, but when I try to output the answer from a button click and an input field it does not work. I changed `felt3.innerHTML=addnumber(ttt);` to `document.write(addnumber(ttt));` which made it work, but it is sending it to another page, which is something I do not want. How I can make this work:

```
<form id="form3">
  Tall:<input type="number" id="number"><br>
  <input type="button" id="button3" value="plusse"><br>
</form>
<div id="felt3"></div>
```

and:

```
var number = document.getElementById("number");

var felt3 = document.getElementById("tall3");

var form3 = document.getElementById("form3");

var button3 = document.getElementById("button3");

var sum=0;

function addnumber(x){
  var array = [];
  array.push(x);
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      sum=sum+array[i];
  }
  return sum;
}

button3.onclick=function(){
  var ttt=Number(number.value);
  felt3.innerHTML=addnumber(ttt);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, then the solution here is to update the argument that you are passing to `getElementById("tall3")`, rewriting it to `document.getElementById("felt3");`.

Doing this will cause your script to aquire the reference to the div element with id `felt3`. When your `onclick` event handler is executed, the result of `addnumber()` will be assigned to the `innerHTML` of the valid `felt3` DOM reference as required:

```js
var number = document.getElementById("number");

// Update this line to use "felt3"
var felt3 = document.getElementById("felt3"); 

var form3 = document.getElementById("form3");

var button3 = document.getElementById("button3");

var sum=0;

function addnumber(x){
  var array = [];
  array.push(x);
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      sum=sum+array[i];
  }
  return sum;
}

button3.onclick=function(){
  var ttt=Number(number.value);
  
  // Seeing that felt3 is now a valid reference to 
  // a DOM node, the innerHTML of div with id felt3
  // will update when this click event is executed 
  felt3.innerHTML=addnumber(ttt);
}
```

```html
<form id="form3">
  Tall:<input type="number" id="number"><br>
  <input type="button" id="button3" value="plusse"><br>
</form>
<div id="felt3"></div>
```

Comment: Oh, ooh. It seems i did not see that. Thanks a lot! :D